# Center multiple Framelayouts within LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains 6 `FrameLayout` blocks.

[image]

Is there any way to center all of the `FrameLayout` blocks within the parent `LinearLayout`? Currently they are further to the left of the screen rather than centered.

Comment: What do you mean "center"? Can you draw a sample pic to illustrate what you want?

Comment: Think alignment. The 6 images were showing left aligned. I need them to be centered within the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `android:layout_gravity="center"` in LinearLayout and `android:gravity="center"` in FrameLayouts to set them  in center. There are other options [see link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android%3agravity)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```